# Looping with a while statement while reading a string for an integer

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, integer

I need help encasing the:

```
if any(c.isdigit() for c in name):
print("Not a valid name!")
```

inside of a while statement. This pretty much just reads the input for the "name" variable and sees if there's an integer in it. How could I use that in a while statement? I just want it to be if the user inputs a variable into the input, it will print out the string up above and loop back and ask the user for their name again until they successfully enter in a string with no integer, then I want it to break. Any help?

```
print("Hello there!")
yn = None
while yn != "y":
    print("What is your name?")
    name = raw_input()
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in name):
        print("Not a valid name!")
    print("Oh, so your name is {0}? Cool!".format(name))
    print("Now how old are you?")
    age = raw_input()
    print("So your name is {0} and you're {1} years old?".format(name, age))
    print("y/n?")
    yn = raw_input()
    if yn == "y":
        break
    if yn == "n":
        print("Then here, try again!")
print("Cool!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `while True` and a `break` to end the loop when a valid name has been entered:

```
while True:
    name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    if not any(c.isdigit() for c in name):
        break
    print("Not a valid name!")
```

This is much easier than first initializing `name` to something that is invalid then using the `any()` expression in the `while` test.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
name = input("What is your name? : ")
while any(c.isdigit() for c in name): 
    print ("{0} is invalid, Try again".format(name))
    name = input("What is your name? : ")
```

demo:

```
What is your name? : foo1
foo1 is invalid, Try again
What is your name? : 10bar
10bar is invalid, Try again
What is your name? : qwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just saying you want a `continue` after your `print("Not a valid name!")`?

```
print("Hello there!")
yn = None
while yn != "y":
    print("What is your name?")
    name = raw_input()
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in name):
        print("Not a valid name!")
        continue
    print("Oh, so your name is {0}? Cool!".format(name))
    ...
```

The `continue` will just go back to the top of your loop.

Comment: Yes, I want it to keep looping until the user enters a valid name (One with no integers)

Comment: So ... isn't this the answer to your question, then?